# Spring Integration not forwarding a custom header?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am adding some headers in `my-transformer`:

```
public Message<?> transform(final Message<?> message) {        
    List<Item> items = doStuff(message);

    final MessageBuilder<?> messageBuilder = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(message.getPayload())
            .copyHeadersIfAbsent(message.getHeaders());


    for (final Item item : items) {
        messageBuilder.setHeader(item.getHeaderName(), item.getValue());
    }

    return messageBuilder.build();
}
```

And I wrote an integration test to confirm that my header is present on the output channel:

```
 public static class HeaderTest extends TransformerTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        channels.input().send(new GenericMessage<>(TransformerTest.EXAMPLE_PAYLOAD));
        final Message<?> out = this.collector.forChannel(this.channels.output()).poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        assertThat(out, HeaderMatcher.hasHeader("header-test", notNullValue()));
    }
}
```

But, when I created a stream like:

```
http --port=1234 | my-transformer | log --expression=toString()
```

and sent the same `EXAMPLE_PAYLOAD` I received the following message in the `log`s log: `GenericMessage [payload=..., headers={kafka_offset=0, id=f0a0727c-9351-274c-58b3-edee9ccbf6ce, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, kafka_receivedTopic=myTopic.my-transformer, timestamp=1485171448947}]`.

Why isn't my `header-test` in the message headers?

-- EDIT --

So if I understood correctly I am supposed to do something like:

```
public class MyTransformer implements Transformer {

    private final EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter converter = new EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter();

    @Override
    public Message<?> transform(final Message<?> message) {
        List<Item> items = doStuff(message);

        final MessageBuilder<byte[]> messageBuilder = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(((String) message.getPayload()).getBytes())
                .copyHeadersIfAbsent(message.getHeaders());

        final int itemsSize = items.size();
        final String[] headerNames = new String[itemsSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsSize; i++) {
            final Item item = items.get(i);
            messageBuilder.setHeader(item.getHeaderName(), item.getValue());
            headerNames[i] = item.getHeaderName();
        }

        final Message<byte[]> msg = messageBuilder.build();

        final byte[] rawMessageWithEmbeddedHeaders;
        try {
            rawMessageWithEmbeddedHeaders = converter.embedHeaders(new MessageValues(msg), headerNames);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new HeaderEmbeddingException(String.format("Cannot embed headers from '%s' into message: %s", items, msg), e);
        }

        return new GenericMessage<>(rawMessageWithEmbeddedHeaders);
    }
}
```

with `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=raw` set in `application.properties` and then convert the message payload on the receiving side? Or can I somehow make the receiving side automatically convert the message payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say whether you are using Spring XD or Spring Cloud DataFlow, but the solution is similar in each case.

Since kafka has no native support for headers, we have to embed them in the message payload. Since we don't want to transport unnecessary headers, you have to opt-in for the headers you want transported by setting the header names in `servers.yml` for Spring XD or `application.yml` (or `.properties`) for a Spring Cloud Stream app.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, there is no support for patterns. One option would be to use the `EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter` yourself, and set the kafka `mode` to raw (on your transformer's output destination). Raw mode means the binder won't embed headers.

That way, the next app (without mode `raw`) should be able to decode the headers as if they had been encoded by the binder in your transformer. [Javadocs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR1/api/index.html?org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.html).

You are limited to 255 headers.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention I am using Spring CDF. The problem is that I don't know my header names in advance. Is there a way to opt-in for all headers in my transformer?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no support for patterns like `*`. I have added a work-around to my answer.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: So I can't convert the message payload automatically then? Because the app after `my-transformer` is getting `GenericMessage [payload=byte[18], headers={kafka_offset=0, id=9fb76cde-0ee9-b5ed-0148-3315085b207c, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=example.my-transformer, header-test=something, timestamp=1485187162288}]` while the input of my transformer was a JSON.

Comment: Ugh, yes; of course, the header embedding done by the binder is after message conversion/serialization. I'll have to play around a bit to see if I can come up with a work-around. I added [an issue to support header patterns in Spring Cloud Stream](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/769).

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll keep my eye on the issue thread and just manually convert for now. Thanks again.